How to publish a project in release configuration in Visual Studio 2022?
The publish wizard in Visual Studio 2022 has no indication of whether I am publishing the debug or release configuration.
I have two questions:

Is there a way to know if I have published the debug or release configuration?

What is the setting that will publish release rather than debug?



You can change the active configuration to Release in the configuration manager and select Release,then publish your package.You can change the active configuration to Release in the configuration manager and select Release,then publish your package.
